# Spring 3.2 properties file auto-wiring fails

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have problems adding properties file to a spring 3.2.2 web application.

My Web.xml:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
                /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


  <!-- Spring Security -->  
 <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.spring</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
 <context:annotation-config/>
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/application.properties"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.model" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.model.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.model.serviceImpl" />
```

I also added the corresponding 'context' schema definition to the xml header.

Additionally there is a spring-security.xml (I don't post the content here).

My class com.mypackage.model.serviceImpl.FeatureServiceImpl reads from the application.properties like this:

```
…
@Autowired
private Environment env;
env.getProperty("db.host");
```

I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'featureController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
…
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.mypackage.model.serviceImpl.FeatureServiceImpl com.mypackage.controller.FeatureController.featureService;
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/application.properties"/>
```

Means you can access the property `db.host` like so:

```
@Value("${db.host}")
private String dbHost;
```

the application.properties file shoud look something like this

```
db.host=myserver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp
db.pwd=mypassword
db.mymultiline = cheesey \
chips \
ketchup
db.another = 42
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and I don't get compilation errors with this.  It reads the file and finds the placeholders. However, the values always resolve to null. Do I need to add something else to the class where I access the properties?

Comment: Nope, just check its called what you think its called.

Comment: I did, it finds the placeholders at runtime. I know it because when I rename the placeholders in the properties file to something else, it complains at runtime. 

I wonder if this kind of injection is supposed to work only in a Controller? I use it in another class which is not a @Controller.

Comment: yes it must be in a spring managend bean such as controller or service

Comment: My Class is annotated with "@Service", but this does not seem to do the trick. As a work-around I did this now: 

I removed the property-placehodler and instead add this to my FeatureServiceImpl class:

`Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("application.properties");
    Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
   
String dbHost = properties.getProperty("db.host");`

I'd still interested how to implement the first way.

Comment: Please make sure that you include spring-expression jar in your classpath
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression/3.2.2.RELEASE